# GridView - Limit group items

Tags: xaml, windows-8

My data is a list of groups, each having an undefined number of items. For the Hubpage I want to limit the items for each group to a specific number. Do I have to create a second collection with only those ten items or is there a XAML way to limit the group items to the top n?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're binding to an IEnumerable off of an [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) (or other Collection type), use the Take extension method to return the Top N.  In the example template, you would do something like ...

```
protected override void LoadState(Object navigationParameter, Dictionary<String, Object> pageState)
{
    // TODO: Create an appropriate data model for your problem domain to replace the sample data
    var sampleDataGroups = SampleDataSource.GetGroups((String)navigationParameter);
    this.DefaultViewModel["Groups"] = sampleDataGroups.Take(5);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Both approaches are possible, but with the caveats. If you would like to use standard XAML controls you would have to effectively create a new collection with as many items as you would like to show. `Take(N)` for example would create new collection with N elements. You could also create your own custom control that will limit amount of visible elements. I general new collection approach is the most common one.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following in the 'Grouped' event of the grid:

```
    if(xamDataGridHotworkS_Flow.FieldLayouts[0].SortedFields.Count > 1)
    {
         xamDataGridHotworkS_Flow.FieldLayouts[0].SortedFields.RemoveAt(1);
    }
```

If there is grouping on the grid, remove the next grouping supplied by the user.

Comment: I asked if there is a possibility to limit the number of items shown in a group even if there are more than the maximum number of items in a group. This is no answer to the question.